# Pasar argumentos fsolve

Tags: python

Quiero resolver un sistema de 7 ecs no lineales en dos bucles (recorro el tiempo y el espacio) y me da problemas en la introducción de los datos, a veces en la función y a veces en el fsolve. Puse el *data para que hiciese el unpacking pero daba problemas. Parece que así normal sí funciona. Cada vez que modifico algo ligeramente me da un problema distinto. Ahora me está dando este problema:
fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.Shape should be
(7,) but it is (7, 20, 30).

```
def equations(data):
    #D,A,S,r,m_f,m_T,rhoV = arg
    Di,ri,x,a,m,rho_f,m_ox = data
    return (D-(Di+2*ri),
            A-np.pi*(D/2)**2,
            S-np.pi*D*x,
            r-((a/(x**m))*rhoV**n),
            m_f-(r*S*rho_f),
            m_T-(m_f+m_ox),
            m_f-(m_T/A))


sol0=np.array([0.01,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.01,0.01,0.1])

for t in range(1,20):
    for i in range(0,L):
        #arg=[D[t,i],A[t,i],S[t,i],r[t,i],m_f[t,i],m_T[t,i],rhoV[t,i]]
        data=[D[t-1,i],r[t-1,i],x[i],a,m,rho_f,m_ox]

        sol[t,i,0:7]=optimize.fsolve(equations,sol0)#,args=data)
        OF[t,i]=m_ox[t,i]/sol[t,i,4]
        sol[t,i,8]=OF[t,i]
```

Comment: Parece que tienes variables globales que no muestras, como `D`, `r`, que tienen pinta de ser arrays, presumo que de dimensiones `(20, L)` y aunque no vemos `L` presumo que sea 30. Las operaciones que haces en `equations` tales como `D-(Di+2*ri)` hacen por tanto una operación vectorial, y su resultado será un array, de las mismas dimensiones que `D` (20x30?). Esto explicaría el error que te da, y es que la función `equations` recibe un parámetro que es un vector de 7 elementos (todos escalares), pero retorna un array multidimensional (una tupla de 7, con algunos elementos de 20x30).

Comment: El resultado de las operaciones debería ser un número. Solo cojo una componente de los arrays. Las variables D y r son globales pero al utilizarlas en la función creía que pasarían a ser locales, no?. Debería declarar variables distintas dentro de la función?. Y lo que he comentado debería descomentarlo y pasarle a la función el argumento arg? (arg son las variables que quiero que me devuelva básicamente, pero no es necesario dárselas como input a la función, por eso no las he incorporado). Siento si alguna de mis observaciones es demasiado obvia, no tengo mucha experiencia en Python. Gracias

Comment: Es mejor evitar confusiones entre variables globales y locales. En principio, cuando una función **asigna** algo a una variable, ésta es local. Pero si lee de una variable a la que no ha asignado nada, se busca el dato en una global. En tu caso asignas cosas a `Di`, por ejemplo, pero no a `D`, por lo que toma la variable global. Si fuera local como tú pensabas ¿qué valor tendría? Yo siento no poder ayudarte mucho pues, aunque si tengo experiencia en Python, no la tengo en el problema que estás tratando de resolver y que no acabo de entender.

Comment: D no sé que valor tendría, eso es lo que quiero saber. Para comenzar una nueva iteración en el bucle externo (tiempo) utilizo las D y r calculadas en el instante justo anterior. El código es para intentar simular la forma de la regresión de un combustible sólido en un cohete híbrido.